# How to make namespace attr in XML code appear on the next line when reformatted

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout, android-xml

Every time I reformat my XML code, `xmlns` moves up to a line where root element's tag name is written.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

**`xmlns:android...`** is next to the `CoordinatorLayout`. I played with XML section of Code Style menu in AndroidStudio, but couldn't do it. 
This is what I want to have when I reformat my layout XML file:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

Can someone help me with this?

This is the XML attribute arrangement in my AndroidStudio:
[image: XML attr arrangement]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Go to `File` -> `Settings` -> `Editor` -> `Code style` -> `XML`.
2. There are 4 submenus (`Tabs and Intents`, `Other`, `Arrangement`, `Android`), select `Android`.
3. On the right side, below the `Layout Files` check both `Insert line break before first attribure`, `Include namespace declarations`.

[image]

Comment: Didn't help... both checked and unchecked didn't have any effect on that. Thanks for the quick response though

Comment: Are you using CTRL + ALT + L to reformat your code?

Comment: I am using Mac, and the shortcut for reformatting is Option+Command+L. I am using this.

Comment: @MirmuhsinSodiqov I edited the answer, check it out.

Comment: Whoaaaa it worked, man, awesome, it turns out I was checking the box under the `AndroidManifest.xml` not under the `Layout Files`. Your answer was right, it was a mistake on my part. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Happy to help you!

Comment: Interestingly, this works for `app/src/main/res/layout/file.xml`, but not for `custom_library_module/src/main/res/layout/file.xml`. It looks like Android Studio does not detect layout xml files from a library module as a layout file. Have you encountered this?